# Google plus ane air native extension failed resolving interface

Tags: android, air, google-plus, google-play-services, air-native-extension

I am attempting to add Google Plus support to an Air mobile app by creating a native extension. The code works in a standalone project however attempting to use it as a native extension produces the following error:

```
Failed resolving Lcom/myname/ane/sharingextensions/googleplus/GooglePlusConnect; interface 479 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
04-08 15:51:29.573: W/dalvikvm(19956): Link of class 'Lcom/myname/ane/sharingextensions/googleplus/GooglePlusConnect;' failed
```

It seems to me that the Google Play Services library is not actually being included in the native extension.
The google-play-services_lib project is added as a library project to my native extension project. I have tried extracting the bin/google-play-services_lib.jar file from the google-play-services_lib project and updating my native extension jar with the contents

```
jar xf /path-to-play-services-project/bin/google-play-services_lib.jar
jar uf ./my_gplus_extension.jar ./android
```

but this does not seem to fix the problem (all that seems to be in there is a single "UnusedStub.class" file). I have also updated the Android SDK in the Adobe Air directory to version 19 (as described here http://lancelotmobile.com/blog/air-compile-for-android-4/) but this also has had no effect.
The offending class is:

```
public class GooglePlusConnect extends FragmentActivity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,
    ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult> {

        //Pretty much a clone of the google plus sign-in sample project
    }
```

It would be great if anyone had any insight into this or can spot any daft mistakes I have made.

Comment: If you have resolved your own question, please post the solution as an answer below and then mark it as correct when you are able to (usually 2 days after you posted the question, if you are answering it yourself).

Comment: I have moved my answer to the reply below, hope this is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I just answered my own question, seems like I need to be extracting the contents of /path-to-play-services-project/libs/google-play-services.jar which actually contains lots of stuff, and corrects that link error when I update my extension jar file with its contents. The following seems to sort it:

```
jar xf /path-to-play-services-project/libs/google-play-services.jar
jar uf ./my_gplus_extension.jar ./com
```

Comment: It turns out manually extracting and updating the jar files is completely unnecessary with AIR 4.0 and above, you just stick the .jar file in the folder with you android library and fill out the dependencies in the platform.xml file. 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2e74ffb4130044f3619-7ff8.html
Just thought I'd stick that here in case anyone stumbles across this and wonders what madness this post is going on about.

Comment: I am using your approach to extract google-play-services.jar and express in my extension.jar. After I debug in my phone, I got problem like: **The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.**  Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: @James If you do not make use of any Google Play resources then this should not be a problem, but to get rid of the warning you can do the following for AIR 4.0: 
Copy the contents of the <android-sdk-path>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res/ to a directory alongside your android implementation .jar and add the following to your platform.xml:
<packagedResources> 
    <packagedResource> 
        <packageName>com.google.android.gms</packageName> 
        <folderName>dir-you-copied-play-res-to</folderName> 
    </packagedResource> 
<packagedResources>

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I can build an ane file. But I have a very strange problem with Google Play service lib. Here is my problem description: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104532/adobe-air-4-0-native-extension-with-google-play-services