# Latest Google Services (v. 21) ANE + AIRMobile native extension failed resolving interface

Tags: android, mobile, google-play-services, air-native-extension

I am trying to add latest Google Plus (**google-play-services.jar**) support to an Air mobile app by creating a native extension. 
The code doesn't have compile-time errors or warnings, the JAR is exported fine, ANE is built and included in project without problems,
but when I run my apk, it crushes. In device-crush-logs I can see following error:

```
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
```

At first I tried to build an extension from empty project, all by myself.
After that I found an extension with open source at github github.com/alextel69/google-play-game-services-ane/
I build that extension and include in my AIR mobile project and it works fine, but the **google-play-services.jar** is too old and doesn't contain classes I need,
so i tried to replace it's **libs/google-play-services.jar** and **libs/android-support-v4.jar** with the newest ones that I got in my Android SDK Manager.
And that caused the above errors.
In this way, I did not modify a single code line, or ANT's build.xml, or anything else, I just switched old **android-support-v4.jar** + **google-play-services.jar** (works fine!) with newer **android-support-v4.jar** + **google-play-services.jar** (fails). I mean the ANE is built fine, even the extension is created and some of it's methods work and return values, but as I referense to google-service code, I get that strange error.

Though interfaces in both old and new JARs seem to be equal: *dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13839683/ane/jars_compare.png* .

By the way, these errors seem to appear in AIR mobile only. Pure native application using these android-support-v4.jar + google-play-services.jar have no problems.

Here is a brief scheme of my native extension:
*dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13839683/ane/scheme.png*

And here is a complete device log from extension's birth and till it's crush :

```
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 I ~ANE~   : ------------- INITIALIZE MY EXTENSION -------------
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 I ~ANE~   : ------------- CREATE MY EXTENSION -------------
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Could not find method com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.onStop, referenced from method com.google.api.games.Context.dispose
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6754: Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;.onStop ()V
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 2701 (Leaderboards) in Lcom/google/android/gms/games/Games;
12-04 11:08:18.602 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0000
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 2700 (Achievements) in Lcom/google/android/gms/games/Games;
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0000
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 2700 (Achievements) in Lcom/google/android/gms/games/Games;
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0000
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 2700 (Achievements) in Lcom/google/android/gms/games/Games;
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0000
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Could not find method com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn, referenced from method com.google.api.games.Context$beginUserInitiatedSignIn.call
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6715: Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;.beginUserInitiatedSignIn ()V
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0009
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Could not find method com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.signOut, referenced from method com.google.api.games.Context$signOut.call
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6767: Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;.signOut ()V
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0009
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.612 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.622 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Could not find method com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.isSignedIn, referenced from method com.google.api.games.Context$isSignedIn.call
12-04 11:08:18.622 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6740: Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;.isSignedIn ()Z
12-04 11:08:18.622 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000a
12-04 11:08:18.622 23195 23195 I ~ANE~   : Context :: testANE.call
12-04 11:08:18.622 23195 23195 I ~ANE~   : Context :: promptUserToSignInOnStartup.call
12-04 11:08:18.622 23195 23195 I ~ANE~~  : Context :: Extension.autoSignIn = true
12-04 11:08:18.622 23195 23195 I ~ANE~   : Context :: start.call
12-04 11:08:18.622 23195 23195 I ~ANE~~  : Context :: start.call[END]
12-04 11:08:18.622   480 26966 I ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=air.com.sq.kitchen/com.google.api.games.SignInActivity} from pid 23195
12-04 11:08:18.712 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6728: Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;.getInvitationId ()Ljava/lang/String;
12-04 11:08:18.712 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-04 11:08:18.712 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.712 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.712 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.712 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.712 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Could not find method com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.getSignInError, referenced from method com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity.getSignInError
12-04 11:08:18.712 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6731: Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;.getSignInError ()Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper$SignInFailureReason;
12-04 11:08:18.712 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-04 11:08:18.732 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.732 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.742 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.742 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Could not find method com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.makeSimpleDialog, referenced from method com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity.showAlert
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6746: Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;.makeSimpleDialog (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/app/Dialog;
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Could not find method com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.signOut, referenced from method com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity.signOut
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6767: Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;.signOut ()V
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; interface 940 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 D dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x1a39 at 0x08 in Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameActivity;.getGameHelper
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 I ~ANE~   : SignInActivity :: onCreate
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 W dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416dbba8)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime: Process: air.com.sq.kitchen, PID: 23195
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity.getGameHelper(Unknown Source)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.api.games.SignInActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-04 11:08:18.762 23195 23195 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 11:08:18.782   480 14720 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity air.com.sq.kitchen/com.google.api.games.SignInActivity
12-04 11:08:18.782   480 14720 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity air.com.sq.kitchen/.AppEntry
```

---

### inb4

---

I discovered this issue very thoroughly and found several simular threads, but none of them resolved my problem

1) The solution of [Google plus ane air native extension failed resolving interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956979/google-plus-ane-air-native-extension-failed-resolving-interface)

> jar xf /path-to-play-services-project/libs/google-play-services.jar
>
> jar uf ./my_gplus_extension.jar ./com

does not fix anything.

2) Any manipulations with Eclipse [Adobe Air 4.0 Native Extension with Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104532/adobe-air-4-0-native-extension-with-google-play-services) don't help either (after all, I am building JAR using ANT).

3) I do modify resourses (\google-play-services_lib\res*.*) when switching to a new google-service-library.

4) I even tried to extend google's interfaces and modified my GameHelper to implement them, but that did not help either (*dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13839683/ane/extend_interface.jpg*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve partially this problem. I asked [the same question on starling-forum](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/latest-google-services-v-21-ane-airmobile-native-extension-failed-resolving#post-73635) and it's member tsangwailam suggested me to replace the dx.jar in AIR SDK to the new one in Android SDK.

replacing dx.jar really helped. I took **%ANDROID_SKD%\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\lib\dx.jar** and copied it into **%FLEXSDK%\lib\android\bin\dx.jar**
and the extension began to work correctly!

but...

as soon as I run an activity SingInActivity

> Intent intent = new Intent(context.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SingInActivity.class);
>   context.getActivity().startActivity(intent);

my application becomes inactive - **fails to handle touches**.
it seems like some invisible modal popup appears and does'n allow my application to catch taps.
after minimizing and restoring my application I see that SingInActivity steps into mehtod "protected void onStart()" and I know my applicatins "sees" it, because I log it using FREContext.dispatchStatusEventAsync() into my Flash's textfield, but application is stil not able to handle user inputs (both native flash and starling/stage3d TouchEvents)
it's an interesting fact, that when my AIR application loses ability to handle touches, android's navigating buttons turn from hidden dots into actual buttons : 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13839683/ane/untouchable.png

as for device log, I don't see there any erros, or Java ecxeptions, or nothing (at least for me) that could explain such behavior.

So what can it be? Maybe there are some other JARs I need to replace?

Comment: It's OK, the activity should be stopped after Google passes an answer (finish(); in onConnectionFailed or onConnected)